# Python Class Decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to decorate an actual class, using this code:

```
def my_decorator(cls):
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        return object.__new__(cls)
    return wrap

@my_decorator
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "__init__ should run if object.__new__ correctly returns an instance of cls"


test = TestClass() # shouldn't TestClass.__init__() be run here?
```

I get no errors, but I also don't see the message from `TestClass.__init__()`.

According to [the docs for new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> Typical implementations create a new instance of the class by invoking the superclass’s `__new__()` method using `super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls[, ...])` with appropriate arguments and then modifying the newly-created instance as necessary before returning it.
>
> If `__new__()` returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.

Any ideas why `__init__` isn't running?

Also, I have tried to call `__new__` like this:

```
return super(cls.__bases__[0], cls).__new__(cls)
```

but it would return a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: super.__new__(TestClass): TestClass is not a subtype of super
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__init__` isn't running because `object.__new__` doesn't know to call it. If you change it to 
`cls.__call__(*args, **kwargs)`, or better, `cls(*args, **kwargs)`, it should work. Remember that a class is a callable: calling it produces a new instance. Just calling `__new__` returns an instance but doesn't go through the initialization. An alternative would be to call `__new__` and then manually call `__init__` but this is just replacing the logic that is already embodied in `__call__`.

The documentation that you quote is referring to calling `super` from *within* the `__new__` method of the class. Here, you are calling it from the outside and not in the usual way as I've already discussed.

Comment: for some reason I thought the act of creating an instance would fire off the `__init__`.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't tell you the reason but this hack does run `__init__`

```
def my_decorator(cls):
    print "In my_decorator()"
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        print "In wrap()"
        return cls.__init__(object.__new__(cls), *args, **kw)
    return wrap

@my_decorator
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "__init__ should run if object.__new__ correctly returns an instance of cls"
```